# How to define custom return type built from multiple entities and values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a spring boot REST application that has to support a legacy database, but implements new funcionalities.
I would like to call a database JPQL query that returns the full in the repositoy aggregated entity but also multiple single values from other entities.
Because the query gives a list of object with each one having its own associated values from the other entities I can not simply create a `List<>` as return type. I read about Spring Boot Data JPA projections. So my idea was to define an interface with including the different types as getters. Projections would be a good solution but I do not see how I can write a projection interface including multiple values from different entities and even whole entity objects while using it as a return type in a spring-boot repository.
The problem is that I can only get values from the entity that is included in the repository declaration but I need a lot of different entities. It kind of works with using tpye `Object` but I think this would be bad practice and also the additional values have no titles in the delivered JSON.

I have simple Entities but can not put any joins directly into the entity. It has all to be done in the repository/services.
So my idea was to define an interface like:

```
public interface OfferWithDate{

Offer getOffer();
LocalDateTime getExpirationDate();
String getPictureUrl

}
```

with an repository like this:

```
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT o, b.expirationDate, p.pictureUrl FROM OfferEntity o +
            "left join BackPackEntity b on o.prsId = b.prsId +"
            "left join PictureEntity p on o.prsId = p.prsId +"
            "where o.accessable = 2 and b.visible = true ")
    List<OfferWithDate> getAllProfiles();
```

I would like for it to be returned by my RESTController something like this (Please excuse if it should look different. But I need it to be a fully serialized JSON):

```
[
    [
        {
            OfferId: 1,
            prsId: 1
        }
        {
            expirationDate: "2021-12-25T09:53:14.27"
        }
        {
            pictureUrl: "https://1234.com"
        }
    ]
]
```

Anything I try leaves me with JSON responses that have all values `null` (because it takes my interface and can not map any values to it). I can not add values from other entities and I can not map the whole Entity to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution.

The missing piece was to define a custom name within the database query:

```
...SELECT o as offer, b.expirationDate as exDate, p.pictureUrl as picUrls FROM...
```

the interface has to match with the given names but still just can look like this:

```
    public interface OfferWithDate{
         Offer getOffer();
         LocalDateTime getExDate();
         String getPicUrl();
}
```

I hope this helps whoever is looking for this :)